# Wrong permissions on configuration file of phpmyadmin

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have installed xampp on Ubuntu 15.04 and after starting the server, I get:

```
phpMyAdmin - Error
Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: It is complaining that you changed the config file and made its permissions "777". Remove it and install our native LAMP stack with `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`.  Less hassle, more secure and made to work out of the box.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments:

`xampp`  is complaining that you changed the config file and made its permissions `777`. (world readable and writeable)

Remove it and install the Ubuntu native LAMP stack with:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server
```

Less hassle, more secure and made to work out of the box.

Answer (score 8):

if you are running  XAMPP on 14.04
this must work

```
sudo chmod 644 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Comment: This command also work on Linux Mint. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Its late but may help someone in future.

If you are using Bitnami LampStack, then you'll find the file `config.inc.php` in

```
install-directory/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/
```

So for changing its permission, open a terminal and excecute:

```
sudo chmod 755 install-directory/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/config.inc.php
```

Then try to reload `localhost/phpmyadmin`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question by typing this command that changes the permission of phpMyadmin.
open terminal and type:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 644 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/setup/frames/
```

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window.

1. Run `sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`.
2. Open `config.inc.php` in a text editor.
3. *(i)* Change `config` to `cookie` on the line that reads:

   ```php
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
   ```

   *(ii)* Keep the next line the same. Do not change it from:

   ```php
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
   ```

   *(iii)* Change `''` to `'root'` on the line that says:

   ```php
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
   ```
4. Save `config.inc.php`.
5. Run `sudo chmod 644 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`.
6. Restart XAMPP and check phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, someone out there having same issue but changing file permission doesn't solve the issue, add this line to your config.inc.php file

```
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
```

Worked for me in Ubuntu !!